# Strings in C++ error C2061

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, header

I'm having a problem with my header file.
For some reason it gives me errors about the strings.
In Header.h I have

```
#include <string>
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
class Player
{
    public:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int birthYear;
    string *matchDates;

    string toString();
    void addMatchDate(string date);
    Player();
    Player(string firstName, string lastName, int birthYear);
    ~Player();
};
#endif
```

But for God knows what reasons, it gives me a bunch of errors.
These are some of the errors:

```
Error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'firstName'   
Error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'lastName'    
Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Use qualified name (`string` is defined in namespace `std`): `std::string`.

Comment: Oh, so I could just add using namespace std?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @user3194111 Prefer to qualify the name: `std::string`, for the reasons in hmjd's link. Also, put the `include` inside the `#ifndef` guard (not that it will make a significant difference, but the point of the guard is to hide *everything* inside the file from being seen twice).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help!
I've also found a problem with creating the function toString in Test.cpp
I've included "Header.h", string, iostream. Namespace std has been declared.
But when trying to create the function,

    Player::toString()
    {}

I get errors saying

Error C2371: 'Player::toString' : redefinition; different basic types 

Error C2556: 'int Player::toString(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'std::string Player::toString(void)'

Error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Answer (score 2):

Name string is defined in the standard name space std.

So either before the class definition use directive

```
using std::string;
```

or specify qualified name

```
std::string
```

whenever you use this type.